# In what header file the function `_tcscpy_s` is declared?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, winapi

Visual Studio 2015. I am reading the "[Windows via C\C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735663777)" book and try to use its code samples. Author writes that the "safe" functions of string have the `_s` suffix and are declared in the `StrSafe.h` header. This header are to be the last in the list of includes. In my code I included such headers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
```

But I have a problem:

```
// IDE doesn't see the _tcscpy_s function
errno_t result = _tcscpy_s(szBuffer, _countof(szBuffer), TEXT("0123456789"));
```

I [looked](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=_tcscpy_s&pgArea=header&emptyWatermark=true&ac=4) for info about the `_tcscpy_s` function, but I didn't see info about its header file (I expected that it is `strsafe.h`).

How can I fix it?

Comment: You should stop using tchar. It was useful when we wanted to compile for Win98 and WinNT. But those days are long gone. Use Unicode text instead.

Comment: Why? Use of TCHAR is flexible. The author of the book recommends to do it.

Comment: No. TCHAR just confuses the heck out of you. It adds loads of complexity for no gain. You aren't targeting Win98. You don't want to cripple the users with ANSI. Use Unicode text. And stop using these C RTL functions anyway and use the C++ std lib string type. In this case `std::wstring`.

Comment: But `TCHAR` is macros. It is Unicode (`wchar_t`) when the `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` are defined in the settings of the project (are user by default). Author recomends to use WinAPI types for clear code. Such types are clear for Windows programmers and agrees for types of MSDN.

Comment: I understand clearly what `TCHAR` is. I also understand why it was introduced and why it is no longer needed. Perhaps you are missing that historical information.

Comment: Thank you, @DavidHeffernan.

Comment: I think TCHAR should still be used, because it's the key to adding string functions that support UTF-8 (it's been explained the XxxxA() functions can't be used for UTF-8 for historical reasons).

Comment: @Medinoc No it isn't. You can use UTF-8 without TCHAR. TCHAR exists solely to single source code targeting Win98 (no Unicode API), and NT. There is a great deal of misunderstanding and misinformation on this topic. It has become cargo cult programming.

Comment: I'll say my point more clearly: It's not just a relic of the past, but also a point of future evolution (which can come from a third party). Also, TCHAR goes hand-in-hand with suffix-less Win32 API functions. Using the `XxxxW()` functions explicitly locks you in a present you assume will never change (despite it having changed at least once in the past) and playing mix-and-match (using suffix-less functions with `wchar_t`) is the same recipe for headache as using suffix-less functions with `char` was!

Comment: @Medinoc This is cargo cult.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Then which do you suggest? explicit W functions, or mix-and-match?

Comment: @Medinoc I don't have any problem with explicit `W` suffixes. I also think it's fine to define `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` and let the macros tack on the `W` suffixes. You don't call the ANSI API ever. If you want to do UTF-8 work then it needs to be converted to/from UTF-16 at the boundary between your code and the Windows API. As close to the boundary as possible.

Comment: @Medinoc: I think I understand your point, but even if MS ever introduced UTF-8 variants of the Win32 API functions (which seems unlikely) there would be no advantage to rebuilding existing code using it.  To actually take advantage of it, you'd need to rewrite the code anyway.  In the meantime, if you use TCHAR and friends, and someone accidentally builds in ANSI rather than Unicode mode, you won't get any warning.  I'd really prefer for the code to fail to build in that scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like any other "Generic Text" string function version, the `_tcscpy_s()` function is declared in `TCHAR.H` (as mentioned in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx)).

Add `#include <tchar.h>` to your code.